# how to find a value between ranges in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My condition is

My query is returning this

```
2             10          150000   where 2=startingslab and 10 = endingslab

11            20          250000

21            31          150000
```

now i want to get the price details for startingslab =3. i.e 15000.I know i need to process it row by row as between is not working.

Is there any way except cursors and while loop to accomplish this.

EDIT

This query returns the above resultset

```
SELECT  dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.SlabStartValue, 
        dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.SlabEndValue,
        convert(int,(@MRP-(dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.Discount*@MRP)/100)) as SlabPrice    
FROM    dbo.TBM_SLAB 
        INNER JOIN dbo.TBM_Slab_Details ON dbo.TBM_SLAB.SlabId = dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.SlabId and  productid=@productID
```

now i have a variable @slabvalue which holds slabvalue.

now for eg @slabvalue=3,I want 150000 from above resultset

if it is 12,I want 250000

Comment: could you expand your question, I don't understand it

Comment: Would you provide some more details about your table structure and the query you execute?

Comment: Looks like maybe the first column is a field containing a range, and he wants to detect the value for the range a given value falls into?

Comment: This can't be answered effectively without your schema...

Comment: Short answer is "yes" you can do this without cursors. If you would please provide the table schema (column names and types) someone here will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'between not working'?

Comment: StartingSlab BETWEEN SlabStartValue AND SlabEndValue should work fine--it is inclusive, just like your ranges suggest it should be. If StartingSlab is a float, you have a problem because of the "holes" between one SlabEndValue and the next SlabStartValue.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  convert(int,(@MRP-(d.Discount*@MRP)/100)) as SlabPrice    
FROM    dbo.TBM_SLAB s
        INNER JOIN dbo.TBM_Slab_Details d ON s.SlabId = d.SlabId and productid=@productID
WHERE   @slabValue >= d.SlabStartValue
        and @slabValue <= d.SlabEndValue
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick blind shot:

```
declare @lab int
select top 1 *
from yourTable
where startingslab >= @lab
order by startingslab asc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SLABStartvalue and SlabEnd value are integer (or other numeric) data types, maybe this would work?

```
declare @Myvariable int
Set @Myvariable = 3

select @Myvariable, slabprice from 
(SELECT  dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.SlabStartValue,         
    dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.SlabEndValue,        
    convert(int,(@MRP-(dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.Discount*@MRP)/100)) as SlabPrice    
FROM    dbo.TBM_SLAB         
INNER JOIN dbo.TBM_Slab_Details 
    ON dbo.TBM_SLAB.SlabId = dbo.TBM_Slab_Details.SlabId and  productid=@productID) a
    where SlabStartValue <= @Myvariable and SlabEndValue>=@Myvariable
```

If they are character type of data you might need to convert them to ints in the where clause to get it to work.